# dynamically add data to QTableView

Tags: qt, append, row, tableview

I'm writing a simple `TableView` according to

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/itemviews-addressbook.html

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QList<QPair<string, int> > data_;
....
```

How to add rows to the model dynamically? `data_.insert(..)` won't change the view, currently I write a function to append new row:

```
void my_append_data(const string& first, int second) {
    int row = rowCount(QModelIndex());
    insertRow(row); // insert a empty row
    // fill the row
    setData(createIndex(row, 0), QVariant::fromValue<string>(first), Qt::EditRole);
    setData(createIndex(row, 1), QVariant::fromValue<int>(second), Qt::EditRole);
}
// usage
model.my_append_data("11111", 111);
model.my_append_data("22222", 222);
```

This seems inefficient cause the `setData` is called twice when append a row, because there're two columns, and there may be more columns in the future.

Any better way to append rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think it's inefficient. However you could make it *simpler*.

I would probably write your function like this, which would make it more future proof against changes to column counts and types:

```
void my_append_data(const QVariantList &data) {
    insertRow(rowCount(QModelIndex()));

    foreach(const QVariant &item, data) {
        setData(createIndex(row, 0), item, Qt::EditRole);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
model.my_append_data(QVariantList() << "11111" << 111);
```

Basic (and most Qt types) can be implicitly converted into `QVariant`s, so there's no need to call`QVariant::fromValue()`

Also if you're using Qt, you would normally be using `QString`s, not `std::string`s.

Comment: This is nice, Thanks Chris.

Comment: I don't see why this code is better then code in question, I would say it is even worse. IMO my answer is much better.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is strange! When you subclassing `QAbstractTableModel` and do some operation on data (on your `data_`) you just have to emit proper signals (or call some protected methods to do such signal emits) to inform views that something was changed in the model!

So in your case it should be something like like:

```
void my_append_data(const string& first, int second) {
    int newRow = data_.count();
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), newRow, newRow);
    data_.append(QPair<string, int>(first, second));
    endInsertRows();
}
```

If other parts of you model are properly written it should work perfectly.

The code written in other answer is just using API designed to be used by views to operate on model. This creates unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I have a question, suppose  - 
1. I have a call MyModelClass which derives QAbstrackTableModel. 
2. My dataSource for the view is created, modified, added, deleted outside of MyModelClass. MyModelClass only holds a pointer/reference of this dataSource. 
3. Now, how do I keep sync between the dataSource and View? 

`data_.append(QPair<string, int>(first, second)); `
I cannot do that, cause the modification happens in another class

Comment: Model is a proxy object to actual data. So if data are modified by some external code, this code should provide some notification mechanism, which you should use to send updates for data model. It depends on details of your problem.